# Linux / iptables - NATing between overlapping subnets

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, routing, wireguard

I'm trying to NAT from one Wireguard interface to another while retaining a private subnet. Here's my setup. The trick here is that I have overlapping subnets on the interfaces.

My VPN server has three interfaces. Public facing `ens3`, personal Wireguard `wg0` (172.16.1.1/24), and VPN service Wireguard `wg1` (172.28.112.173/12)

`ens3` is a public interface with a routable public ipv4 address that has access to the internet

`wg0` is a Wireguard interface for all of my devices on the 172.16.1.0/24 network. All my devices are connected to this interface and can communicate with each other, and are currently NATd out to use `ens3`.

`wg1` is a Wireguard tunnel to a VPN provider on the 172.16.0.0/12 network. The VPN provider assigns an IP address and the router this interface that goes out to the public internet is on 172.16.0.1.

When I set iptables to NAT to `ens3`, everything works as expected. Devices on 172.16.1.0/24 can communicate with each other and also get out to the internet using `ens3`'s public interface

When I set iptables to NAT to `wg1`, devices cannot get out to the internet using `wg1`'s public interface. In fact, tcpdump shows the box is forwarding the packets coming from `wg0` to the router on `ens3` which obviously doesn't work.

My end goal is to get clients `wg0` to NAT out to `wg1`. The subnets that are on `wg0` and `wg1` can't be reassigned or changed. I have a feeling this can be done with policy based routing but after spending a few days on this and trying many different configurations I still can't get it to work. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could offer me some insight!

---

iptables dump:

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Jun 19 03:43:54 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [15677:1866069]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10279:816931]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5314:492688]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4806:467393]
-A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m comment --comment "Also allow 1701/udp for WireGuard" -j REDIRECT --to-ports 500
-A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "Also allow 443/udp for WireGuard" -j REDIRECT --to-ports 500
-A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 19 03:43:54 2021
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Jun 19 03:43:54 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [2775:810347]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1048627:1182856653]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [14961117:11097488012]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow ALL RELATED, ESTABLISHED" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "Allow ALL from lo" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "Allow ICMP" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment "Allow SSH" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wg0 -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "Allow ALL from wg0" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 500 -m comment --comment "Allow WireGuard" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m comment --comment "Clamp MSS to PMTU" -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun 19 03:43:54 2021
```

routing table dump:

```
default via 161.129.xxx.xxx dev ens3
161.129.xxx.xxx/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 161.129.xxx.xxx
172.16.1.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.1
```

Comment: Overlapping is an issue. In the rare case where your VPN provider gives you an IP address in the 172.16.1.0/24 range on wg1 or worse the very same IP address 172.16.1.1 as used on wg0, handling this case would be very awkward if possible at all and would surely have corner cases. Or are you given a static IP? You should bury one of the wg interfaces in an other namespace to hide the problem.